# What is suitable method for controlling lighting based on pause/play?

Tags: electrical, home-automation, design, home-theater, software

I am in the process of turning my basement into a Home Theater. I have seen some people with home theaters where when they pause a movie it dims the lights up and I would love to use this feature. What is a suitable method to achieve this effect?

Comment: Never heard of this, but now that I know about it, I _really_ want it...

Comment: check out logitech 880 / 890 and zwave lighting controll , I found some chatter about them and programming them with a sequence to do just this.  the remote must have the capability to talk to the "dimmer" RF or IR , i am not sure if you have ever seen the old X10 system it could dim  or turn off lights all over your house from 1 place using RF so it is probably RF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent installed but have seen them they have a special remote that has a reciever in the lighting device (switch) you can program the remote for different settings like when you stop a movie lights on full, pause at 50% play at 25% will look arround and see if i can find some brands for you to check out

Comment: Getting a brand name or model would be awesome!

Comment: The [Logitech Harmony](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/harmony-remotes) remotes have the ability to control lights and other "smart-home" devices, but I don't think they can do it to the level of "dim lights when I pause".  I have a Harmony Ultimate, and it can't do that.

Comment: I am not sure of the brand that I saw , was installing some new lighting for a contractor I work for on the side he showed it to me it had 3 levels of lighting but I really dont remember the brand of the remote , It may have been a small tablet that was programmed but it also did the curtians and the HVAC controlls

Comment: Lutron and Leviton both have controllers that can control motorized blinds and thermostats. I think with Leviton's LevNet you can only use Leviton thermostats but Lutron I know works with at least Honeywell, possibly NEST? I have some Lutron stuff that works very well but I haven't done much integration with it. You can maybe get a WINK Hub and integrate it with IFTTT.com to possibly control the lights based on pause button if the remote or the DVD/DVR can also somehow trigger things on IFTTT.